# Splunk Free giving error while installing new app

Tags: ubuntu, splunk

I am using Splunk Free on my local Ubuntu machine. I have added a datasource to monitor and it's working properly.

Splunk Free Version - 8.1.1
Ubuntu Version - 20.04.1 LTS

The issue is, when I try to install a new app i.e. **Splunk Add-on for Unix and Linux**.
Even for valid credentials its saying **Incorrect Username or Password** for both Splunk Admin and Splunk User.

Bdw, with same credentials I am able to login to Splunk.com

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When downloading apps directly to Splunk you must provide your splunk.com credentials in the Manage Apps screen.

If you still can't get it to work then use the indirect method.  Download from splunkbase to your workstation and then upload from there to Splunk using the "Install from file" button in the Manage Apps screen.

Answer (score 0):

This issue will be resolved once you verify your email ID by clicking on the link in 'Welcome to Splunk - Verify Your Email Address' email.